# Get Specific Field from Firestore with whereEqualTo

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase document and i want to extract fields values to TextView in adnroid where the currentuser id from mAuth equals the user-id field inside the document **but it's not working** 
[Firebase Document Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sClpw.png)

```
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.collection("users")
                .whereEqualTo("user-uid",uid)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                         user_name = task.getResult().getString("user-name");
                         user_email = task.getResult().getString("user-email");
                         user_last_name = task.getResult().getString("user-last-name");
                         user_phone_number = task.getResult().getString("user-phone-number");

                    }
                  });
```

Comment: what do you mean by its not working? the value did not come out?

Comment: @Ticherhaz yess, when i add `settings_fragment_user_name.setText(user_name); `it still empty and not getting the value from firestore

Comment: please use this to check either the task is success or not. use this. `if (task.isSuccessfull){ // do something }`

Comment: @Ticherhaz `if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"success accessing database",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                                user_name = document.get("user-name").toString();
                            }
                        } ` i get the Toast but still no data

Comment: Have you tried to check what happens if the Task is not successful?

Comment: Please edit your question to show in one snippet how you read the data from Firestore **and** then set it to the views of your app? Right now there is not enough information for us to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
db.collection("users")
                .whereEqualTo("user-uid",uid)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"success accessing database",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                                //Fetch from database as Map
                                user_name = (String) document.getData().get("user-name");
                                user_last_name =(String) document.getData().get("user-last-name");
                                user_phone_number =(String) document.getData().get("user-phone-number");
                                user_email =(String) document.getData().get("user-email");
```

Comment: Did this code solve the issue you were facing? It's unclear if that is the case since you only posted the code.

Comment: @RafaelLemos yess this is the solution, it worked perfectly